How create pipes to non-standard file descriptors using posix_spawn on C++
I have a situation when I try to launch a process (Chrome originally) with posix_spawn on MacOS. This code should work on Linux as well, but I haven't tested yet.
I want to create pipes for descriptors 1 (STDOUT), 2 (STDERR) and also 3 (write) and 4 (read).
It doesn't work with Chrome, and I'm trying to test this case with a simple code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import time
import fcntl

print("fcntl 3:", fcntl.fcntl(3, fcntl.F_GETFD))
print("fcntl 4:", fcntl.fcntl(4, fcntl.F_GETFD))

fd4 = os.fdopen(4, 'wb')
while True:
    print('Cycle')
    time.sleep(2)
    while chunk := os.read(3, 1024):
        print('REQ:', chunk.decode('utf8', errors='backslashreplace'), file=sys.stderr)
        fd4.write(b'FOO')

I'm trying to check if descriptors are reachable. Descriptor 3 is ready for reading, and data can be read from it.
But descriptor 4 is not accessible, an attempt to open it or test with fcntl leads to an error "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor". And Chrome fails on the same try.
Here is the C++ code (simplified a little) with posix_spawn that leads to this situation:
#include "pipes.h"

#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

extern "C" char** environ;

constexpr int CDP_WRITE_FILENO = 3;
constexpr int CDP_READ_FILENO = 4;

void RunBrowser(const char* exePath, const std::vector<const char*>& launchArgs) {
    posix_spawn_file_actions_t childFdActions{};
    posix_spawn_file_actions_init(&childFdActions);
    DEFER(&childFdActions) {
        posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy(&childFdActions);
    };

    int stdoutPipe[2];
    int stderrPipe[2];
    int cdpWritePipe[2];
    int cdpReadPipe[2];
    if (pipe(stdoutPipe) || pipe(stderrPipe) || pipe(cdpWritePipe) || pipe(cdpReadPipe)) {
        throw TBrowserError() << "Could not create a pipe: " << std::strerror(errno);
    }
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&childFdActions, stdoutPipe[0]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&childFdActions, stderrPipe[0]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&childFdActions, cdpWritePipe[1]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&childFdActions, cdpReadPipe[0]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&childFdActions, stdoutPipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&childFdActions, stderrPipe[1], STDERR_FILENO);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&childFdActions, cdpWritePipe[0], CDP_WRITE_FILENO);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&childFdActions, cdpReadPipe[1], CDP_READ_FILENO);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&childFdActions, stdoutPipe[1]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&childFdActions, stderrPipe[1]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&childFdActions, cdpWritePipe[0]);
    posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&childFdActions, cdpReadPipe[1]);

    pid_t childPid{};
    if (const int ret = posix_spawn(&childPid, exePath,
                                    &childFdActions, nullptr,
                                    const_cast<char* const*>(launchArgs.data()),
                                    environ)) {
        throw TBrowserError() << "Failed to spawn a process: " << std::strerror(ret);
    }

    close(stdoutPipe[1]);
    close(stderrPipe[1]);
    close(cdpWritePipe[0]);
    close(cdpReadPipe[1]);

    int status;
    do {
        const int ret = waitpid(childPid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        if (ret == -1) {
            kill(childPid, SIGKILL);
            throw TBrowserError() << "waitpid error: -1";
        }

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            const auto retCode = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            if (retCode == 0) {
                break;
            }
            throw TBrowserError() << std::format("Browser process failed with exit code {}", retCode);
        }

        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            throw TBrowserError() << "Browser process killed by signal " << WTERMSIG(status);
        }

        if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            std::cerr << "Browser process stopped by signal " << WSTOPSIG(status) << std::endl;
        }

        if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
            std::cerr << "Browser process is continued" << std::endl;
        }
    } while (WIFEXITED(status) || WIFSIGNALED(status));
}


This is just a speculation:
First, pipe(stdoutPipe) occupies file descriptors 3 and 4 in the parent process. (The other pipe() calls occupy later file descriptors, but this is not relevant.)
Then in the client:

p_s_f_a_addclose(&childFdActions, stdoutPipe[0]); closes descriptor 3.
p_s_f_a_adddup2(&childFdActions, cdpWritePipe[0], CDP_WRITE_FILENO); makes descriptor 3 usable.
p_s_f_a_adddup2(&childFdActions, cdpReadPipe[1], CDP_READ_FILENO); makes descriptor 4 usable.
p_s_f_a_addclose(&childFdActions, stdoutPipe[1]); closes descriptor 4.

The last action makes the file descriptor unusable in the client.
As a solution, you can do the adddup2 calls first, and then add all the addclose calls, but only if they do not close one of the file descriptors 0 to 4.

+1 this is it.  May I suggest it'd be clearer and more maintainable to pair the dup2/close calls, rather than separate them and simply remember not to close the wrong ones?  That is, dup2(stdoutPipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO); close(stdoutPipe[1]); — the code is really looking to "move" the pipe write-end file description from its original fd to STDOUT_FILENO, and then discard that original fd.  No sense separating those actions.  (I wish we all had an fd_move convenience.)

That can make sense. After that, the code still depends on that stdin, stdout and stderr are open in the parent, so that the pipe() calls allocate file descriptors starting at 3.
